# Clarification date output

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
import java.time.*;

public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //three classes in time class
        System.out.println(LocalDate.now());
        System.out.println(LocalTime.now());
        System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now());
   
        //full date of static method
        public static LocalDateTime of(int year, Month month, int dayOfMonth, int hour, int minute, int second, int nanos)
            LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.of(2020, Month.OCTOBER, 24, 10, 5, 30, 1);
            System.out.println(date);
   
            //manipluating date
            LocalDateTime currentDate = LocalDateTime.now();
            System.out.println(currentDate);
   
            currentDate = date.plusDays(2);
            System.out.println(currentDate);
   
            currentDate = date.plusMonths(2);
            System.out.println(currentDate);
   
            currentDate = date.plusYears(1000);
            System.out.println(currentDate);
   
            currentDate = date.minusYears(1000);
            System.out.println(currentDate);
        }
}
```

After running the above code output on the last current date returns 1020 instead of 2020 . Is there any option to resolve this.

Comment: Because you subtract a thousand years?

Comment: Your changes are not cumulative if you keep creating an instance form the unchanging date property.

Comment: Please carefully format your question. As you can see the code is not all formatted.

Answer (score 1):

You are always manipulating on `date` variable, but the methods you call do not change it, they are only stored in `currentDate` variable, and `date` is left intact. Meaning, every calculation made in your code snippet is date addition/subtraction from the `24th october 2020 10:05:30.000000001`.

```
   currentDate = date.plusDays(2);
   System.out.println(currentDate);

   currentDate = date.plusMonths(2);
   System.out.println(currentDate);

   currentDate = date.plusYears(1000);
   System.out.println(currentDate);

   currentDate = date.minusYears(1000);
   System.out.println(currentDate);
```

All of the above used: `plusDays`,  `plusMonths`, `plusYears` and `minusYears` will calculate the new date from the one you use them on according to passed method parameter, and will RETURN as a result a new date(time) - but unless you store the changes explicitly again into the `date` variable, it will keep it's orginal state.